# How to use Regexp_replace to remove a pattern string

Tags: sql

Right now, I am using Regexp_replace function to remove these patterns \u0..... out of the answer column. Please help create a pattern to match those string to remove it out. Also, these are pulled from Type_form and I don't know why it has these patterns in my answer column, if anyone knows the meaning of this pattern, please explain to me too.

answer_trim

```
Checkout
Fitting Rooms
Products
Returns/Refund
Staff
Store Layout
\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e04\u0e37\u0e19\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32\u0e41\u0e25\u0e30\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e04\u0e37\u0e19\u0e40\u0e07\u0e34\u0e19 Returns/Refund
\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e04\u0e37\u0e19\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32\u0e41\u0e25\u0e30\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e04\u0e37\u0e19\u0e40\u0e07\u0e34\u0e19
\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e08\u0e31\u0e14\u0e27\u0e32\u0e07\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32\u0e41\u0e25\u0e30\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e08\u0e31\u0e14\u0e23\u0e49\u0e32\u0e19 Store Layout
\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e08\u0e31\u0e14\u0e27\u0e32\u0e07\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32\u0e41\u0e25\u0e30\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e08\u0e31\u0e14\u0e23\u0e49\u0e32\u0e19
\u0e08\u0e38\u0e14\u0e0a\u0e33\u0e23\u0e30\u0e40\u0e07\u0e34\u0e19 Checkout
\u0e08\u0e38\u0e14\u0e0a\u0e33\u0e23\u0e30\u0e40\u0e07\u0e34\u0e19
\u0e1e\u0e19\u0e31\u0e01\u0e07\u0e32\u0e19 Staff
\u0e1e\u0e19\u0e31\u0e01\u0e07\u0e32\u0e19
\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32 Products
```

These are raw data that I have been trying to remove it to have only answer

answer

```
{"label": "Checkout"}
{"label": "Fitting Rooms"}
{"label": "Products"}
{"label": "Returns/Refund"}
{"label": "Staff"}
{"label": "Store Layout"}
{"label": "\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e04\u0e37\u0e19\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32\u0e41\u0e25\u0e30\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e04\u0e37\u0e19\u0e40\u0e07\u0e34\u0e19 Returns/Refund"}
{"label": "\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e04\u0e37\u0e19\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32\u0e41\u0e25\u0e30\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e04\u0e37\u0e19\u0e40\u0e07\u0e34\u0e19"}
{"label": "\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e08\u0e31\u0e14\u0e27\u0e32\u0e07\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32\u0e41\u0e25\u0e30\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e08\u0e31\u0e14\u0e23\u0e49\u0e32\u0e19 Store Layout"}
{"label": "\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e08\u0e31\u0e14\u0e27\u0e32\u0e07\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32\u0e41\u0e25\u0e30\u0e01\u0e32\u0e23\u0e08\u0e31\u0e14\u0e23\u0e49\u0e32\u0e19"}
{"label": "\u0e08\u0e38\u0e14\u0e0a\u0e33\u0e23\u0e30\u0e40\u0e07\u0e34\u0e19 Checkout"}
{"label": "\u0e08\u0e38\u0e14\u0e0a\u0e33\u0e23\u0e30\u0e40\u0e07\u0e34\u0e19"}
{"label": "\u0e1e\u0e19\u0e31\u0e01\u0e07\u0e32\u0e19 Staff"}
{"label": "\u0e1e\u0e19\u0e31\u0e01\u0e07\u0e32\u0e19"}
{"label": "\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32 Products"}
{"label": "\u0e2a\u0e34\u0e19\u0e04\u0e49\u0e32"}




(CASE WHEN a.type = 'multiple_choice'
THEN (
    CASE WHEN SPLIT_PART(a.answer, ' ', 1) = '{"label":'
      THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM('"' FROM LTRIM(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.answer, 
   '{"label":'), '}'), ' ')), '')
        ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM('"' FROM LTRIM(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.answer, 
   '{"other":'), '}'), ' ')), '') END
   )
    ELSE a.answer END)
```

I expected a pattern code that can match those pattern string and remove it out.

Comment: You should tag your question with the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for PostgreSql which I assume is what you are using judging by SPLIT_PART and REGEXP_REPLACE

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(a.answer, '^\{"label": "(\\u0e[0-9a-z]{2})*([\w\s/]*)"\}', '\2')
```

I assume the codes you have like \u0e40 represents Unicode characters